# How to copy a value from a cell to various cells VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I will like to do something like this using VBA in Excel.
I need to copy each value in column A(text or numeric) and the format of the cell to the column B twice . 
The result should be like this :

[image]
How can this be done in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a dozen different answers to this question as you are not being very precise. Yet, this is one possible answer:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
Dim lngRow As Long

For lngRow = 1 To 4
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow, 1).Formula = "=row()"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow + lngRow - 1, 2).Formula = "=A" & lngRow
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow + lngRow, 2).Formula = "=A" & lngRow
Next lngRow

End Sub
```

Comment: But what about if I have 1000 values in the column A? I need to have a loop trough all this cells.

Comment: Then change the line `For lngRow = 1 to 4` and make it `For lngRow = 1 to 100`.

Comment: I just add an answer becuse I don´t know why I can´t edit the comment

Comment: I provided an answer to your question. If you prefer your solution then that's fine with me. If you have a **new** question and need help to figure out why "your" code is not working then you should post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

```
Dim c As Range
For Each c In ws.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
ActiveSheet.Cells(c.Value, 1).Formula = "=row()"
ActiveSheet.Cells(c.Value + c.Value - 1, 2).Formula = "=A" & c.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(c.Value + c.Value, 2).Formula = "=A" & c.Value
```

Next c
Next ws

End Sub

But if I put a non-numeric value in the first column it does not work. What I am missing?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you spend a few seconds reading "your" code and you will come to realize that there is no question. As you said yourself: "...if you try to use your code with non-numeric values then it doesn't work." That's obvious since you are using a non-numeric value in a calculation. Example: if you try it with the non-numeric value "x" then your code would yield this in the last row: `ActiveSheet.Cells("x" + "x", 2).Formula = "=Ax"`. That's why my solution is **not** based on the `cell.Value`.